# Esxi TPM attestation failed with "Internal Failure" on VCenter

Tags: vmware, esxi, vsphere, vcenter, ftpm

How to enable TPM 2.0 on esxi host? when I connect esxi to vcenter it shows "TPM attestation failed" and the error message is "Internal Failure". This is the content of vpxd.log

```
2021-07-01T17:04:31.1892 warning vpxd[06035] [Originator@6876 sub=Attestation opID=kq13umtr-824-auto-mx-h5:70000523-ae] Failed to establish root of trust; [vim.HostSytem:host-1017,ryzen-esxi.mydomain.com], N3Vim5Fault8TpmFault9ExceptionE(Fault cause: vim.fault.TpmFault)
```

I have restart, disconnected and reconnected host multiple times

My mobo is Gigabyte x570 pro and on bios it shows TPM 2.0 is enabled as well as secure boot

vCenter is installed as a VM under the esxi host
esxi version: 7.0 Update 1

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are attempting to enable the TPM?

Comment: Of course, I want to install windows 11 inside VM

Comment: TPM isn’t required to run Windows 11 within a VM; This doesn’t mean that vCenter (ESXi) will be compatible with Windows 11 without an update.